# System Verilog: Casting from logic to int

Tags: casting, int, logic, system-verilog

I am trying to cast a 'logic [2:0]' type to an integer in system verilog. It took me awhile to realize this was the problem why my test was not working as expected.

I was trying to cast it like this:

```
int a = int '(signal);
```

Where signal is a logic [2:0]. But this was always assigning a as 0.

Currently this code:

```
     int a;
     if(signal=== 3'b000) begin
        a = 0;
     end else if(signal=== 3'b001) begin
        a = 1;
     end else if(signal=== 3'b010) begin
        a = 2;
     end else if(signal=== 3'b011) begin
        a = 3;
     end else begin
        assert(0);
     end
```

works but I would really like to be able to cast this type.

I really could not find this addressed in ANY sites, book, or stackoverflow thread so if someone finds a duplicate I will be thoroughly embarrassed

Answer (score 6):

You should not need a cast to go from `logic` to `int`. SystemVerilog implicitly casts all integral types. The only issue is if a bit in your `signal` is set to X or Z, then the value gets converted to 0. What you probably want to do is

```
assert (!$isunknown(signal))
       a = signal;
else
  $error("signal is unknown");
```

Comment: How about int to logic may I ask?

Comment: SystemVerilog does not require casting in either direction. It does not need casting between any integral types. But I do suggest using them when there will be loss of information like truncation, X to 0, or sign. It shows the user's intent and is aware of the loss.